# Waiting in a For loop for a callback before next loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, callback

I have a moderately simple for loop which looks like this:

```
for (NSObject *obj in objectsArray)
{
    [DoThingToObject:obj complete:^{
        //Do more
    }];
}
```

I need to do a thing on every object in my array. However, before I start looping and doing  a thing on the second object, I need to wait for the completion call back to occur on the first object.

How can I simply, wait, then do the next object in the loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would be great if objective c had promises, but until then, I usually handle things like this with recursion, using the input array as a to-do list...

```
- (void)doThingToArray:(NSArray *)array then:(void (^)(void))completion {

    NSInteger count = array.count;
    // bonus feature: this recursive method calls its block when all things are done
    if (!count) return completion();

    id firstThing = array[0];
    // this is your original method here...
    [self doThingToObject:firstThing complete:^{
        NSArray *remainingThings = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, count-1)];
        [self doThingToArray:remainingThings then:completion];
    }];
}
```

This works fine for short arrays.  Let me know if the array is large (thousands of elements) and I can show you how to recurse in a way that won't wind up the stack (by making the `doThing` method take a single parameter and "recursing" with performSelector).

**EDIT** - perform selector lets the current run loop finish and queues up the selector for next time.  This saves winding up the stack as you recurse over a long array, but it takes only one param, so we must make the method a little less readable by consolidating the array and block params into a single collection object...

```
- (void)doThingToArray2:(NSDictionary *)params {

    NSArray *array = params[@"array"];
    void (^completion)(void) = params[@"completion"];

    NSInteger count = array.count;
    // bonus feature: this recursive method calls its block when all things are done
    if (!count) return completion();

    id firstThing = array[0];
    // this is your original method here...
    [self doThingToObject:firstThing complete:^{
        NSArray *remainingThings = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, count-1)];
        [self performSelector:@selector(doThingToArray2:)
                   withObject:@{@"array": remainingThings, @"completion": completion}
                   afterDelay:0];
    }];
}

// call it like this:
NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, @3];
void (^completion)(void) = ^void(void) { NSLog(@"done"); };
[self doThingToArray2:@{@"array": array, @"completion": completion}];

// or wrap it in the original method, so callers don't have to fuss with the 
// single dictionary param
- (void)doThingToArray:(NSArray *)array then:(void (^)(void))completion {
    [self doThingToArray2:@{@"array": array, @"completion": completion}];
}
```

Comment: Whether or not OP needs the method mentioned at the end, I'd be curious to see a quick sketch thereof.